# How to perform subtraction on a single element of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor that consists of 4 floats, called `label`.

How do I with a 50% chance execute `x[0] = 1 - x[0]`?

Right now I have:

```
label = tf.constant([0.35, 0.5, 0.17, 0.14]) # just an example
uniform_random = tf.random_uniform([], 0, 1.0)

# Create a tensor with [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] if uniform_random > 50%
# else it's only zeroes
inv = tf.pack([tf.round(uniform_random), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

label = tf.sub(inv, label)
label = tf.abs(label) # need abs because it inverted the other elements
# output will be either [0.35, 0.5, 0.17, 0.14] or [0.65, 0.5, 0.17, 0.14]
```

which works, but looks extremely ugly. Isn't there a smarter/simpler way of doing this?

Related question: How do I apply a certain op (e.g. sqrt) just to two elements? I'm guessing I have to remove these two elements, perform the op and then concat them back to the original vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tf.select`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#select) and [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#cond) come in handy for situations where you have to perform computations conditionally on elements of a tensor. For your example, the following would work :

```
label = tf.constant([0.35, 0.5, 0.17, 0.14])
inv = tf.pack([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
mask = tf.pack([1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0])
output = tf.cond(tf.random_uniform([], 0, 1.0) > 0.5,
                 lambda: label,
                 lambda: (inv - label) * mask)
with tf.Session(''):
  print(output.eval())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply! I had the impression that it was recommended to avoid touching the control flow as much as possible, is that the case or is it not really that important?